# Why does FQL return different user IDs to Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I want to see which users can see a particular album. I use the following query to get my albums and their privacy settings:

```
SELECT id,allow,deny,description,friends,value FROM privacy WHERE id IN
(SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner=me())
```

and it returns something like this for each album:

```
{
  "id": 212102865605678, 
  "allow": "211824028961234,212367312342178", 
  "deny": null, 
  "description": "John Doe, Work People", 
  "friends": "SOME_FRIENDS", 
  "value": "CUSTOM"
}
```

The second ID in the allow column is right. That's the ID for the 'Work People' friendlist.

But the other ID isn't really the ID of 'John Doe'.

If I use the FB.api from javascript using 'me/friends' I get this:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe", 
  "id": "100005318169867"
}
```

Same name, but different ID. I'm quite certain that they're the same user (I don't have many friends). Is this the difference between some internal database ID and external ID?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I don't have many friends" LOL (:

Comment: If you add one more friend, the 211824028961234 would change, but it's still remains 2 id. This id is obviously not represent a single friend user id.

Comment: That would explain it, but from the docs, the description of the allow field is this: "The UIDs of the specific users or the IDs of friendlists that can see the object (as a comma-separated string)"

Comment: Seem like you should file a new bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create