# How to get current uid via fql

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql

```
select uid from user where uid=752688044744924
```

I want to get a person facebook uid

I use this tool
[facebook fql tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=Input%20FQL%20query,%20%3CTab%3E%20to%20autocomplete) to query uid,
the uid is 100000112054287, It's current.

but I get a uid= 752688044744924 on android.

```
public void onCompleted(Response response) 
{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(response.getError()==null)
        {
            JSONArray jsonArrayData=null;

            try 
            {   
                JSONObject  json= response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                jsonArrayData = json.getJSONArray(FqlQuerySyntax.JSON_DATA);    
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for(int i=0;i<jsonArrayData.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonArrayData.opt(i);   


                try 
                {
                    data.uid=jsonObject.getString("uid");
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }


        }

    }
```

if I use "select uid from user where uid=752688044744924" or "select uid from user where uid=100000112054287" on facebook fql tool, I only get the same uid="100000112054287"

Comment: Can you print the `jsonArrayData` content? `jsonArrayData.toString()`

Comment: jsonArrayData.toString() = [{"uid":752688044744924}]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203787/why-does-fql-return-different-user-ids-to-graph-api

it's the same problem